# Vue mouseevents loses reference outside of an element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a multi slider range component with Vue. The most suitable example that i've found is the following: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-price-range-slider-forked-czw1d

I'm trying to refactor its code and i've come to an issue... On `PriceRangeSlider.vue` we have code looping through `["mouseup", "mousemove"]` on line 153 to add those events to document.body.

I've moved these events directly to track1 and track2 elements using @mouseup and @mousemove native vue methods. The problem is that now dragging only occurs if the mouse is exactly inside of those elements. I want that even if I move outside of its element, without mouseup, still drags.

What i've done is on this link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-price-range-slider-forked-ubzxf

it's the same code, but I've made those changes said above.

Can anyone help me to understand why this thing happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track mousemove event on body, rather than on this element. So this code

```
   "mousemove",
      "touchstart",
      "touchmove",
      "touchend",
    ].forEach((type) => {
      document.querySelector(".track1").addEventListener(type, (ev) => {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        self[type](ev, "track1");
      });
```

Is not valid on your case.  What you need is

1. onclick = () =>  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', yourHandler)
2. document.body.addEventListener([mouseup, mouseleave], () =>  document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', yourHandler)
3. Your handler should move the value based of offset to previous event.